# How to cache firestore documents in flutter?

Tags: flutter, caching, google-cloud-firestore

I want to store documents that I download from firestore. Each document has a unique id so I was thinking of a way I can store that document in json format or in database table (so I can access its fields) and if that id is not present in the memory than just simply download it from firestore and save it. I also want these documents to be deleted if they are not used/called for a long time. I found this [cache manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager) but was unable to understand how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

you can download the content by using any of the  flutter downloadmanager and keep the path of the downloaded content in sqllite and load the data from local storage rather than url if the data is already saved.

Following pseudo-code may help you:

```
if(isDownloaded(id)){
//show from local;
} else {
//  show from remote
}
```

you can manually check whether the resources are being used or not by keeping a timestam of it and update the timestamp only when it is  shown. and you can run a service which looks for the unused resources and delete it from storage and the databse too.

Comment: yes that is one hands on brute force way to do it. But I was thinking if  there is a package for this like flutter_cache_manager_firebase: ^1.0.1 (tho I still dont understand how to use this)